# cleaning up tags

Tags: discussion, tags

I see questions with the tags "bldc", "brushless" and "brushless-dc", often more than one of them for a question. Can these be combined into a single "bldc" (I believe that's the most common name)? I don't have enough rep to propose tag synonyms.

Comment: Good question, actually when you do have enough rep to propose / vote on one the other issue is you need need to have a score of five on each tag to do either. There are a few oustanding ones I'd like to give a vote but can't because while I'm familiar with them don't happen to have answered questions on them.

Comment: @PeterJ: I noticed the score-of-five condition. That may not seem like much, but I wonder why this is required. Even without direct involvement in one of the questions I can tell that "bldc" and "brushless-dc" are equivalent. (Maybe I should make that a new question.)

Comment: I guess see what answers you get to this one first. I agree though, and conversely I have a few 5+ tags on things I consider I know little about just because of how questions happened to be tagged.

Comment: It makes sense to consolodate tags, but don't pick the most obscure one. Abbreviations can lead to confusion, especially since people are here asking about such topics. Better to say *Brushless DC Motor* than *BLDC*. Even if you do use a abbreviation, at least always capitalize it. Definitely don't ever use *bldc*.